# Ubuntu on Virtualbox using Intel 12th gen CPU AlderLake show one core only

Tags: virtualbox, windows, virtualization

After installation of Ubuntu in Virtualbox on a Win11 Host linux shows only 1 core but 16 are configured.

[image]

Also ubuntu in Virtualbox is pretty slow, I assume its only one core indeed. Any idea?

### lscpu -e

I executed also the command `lscpu -e` and this appears:

[image]

Comment: How many of your 16 cores did you assign to your vm?   Usually that's a runtime option.

Comment: @ubfan1 You can see in the hardcopy above I assigned 16 cores of my 32 core-system.

Comment: Something like `lscpu -e` would also show offline CPUs to get a better idea what is missing. And maybe it is slow as your system might not allow HW acceleration, which would also limit the CPUs to one - see https://superuser.com/questions/752336/change-number-of-cpus-in-virtualbox-is-disabled#:~:text=To%20enable%20more%20than%201,V)%20in%20the%20Acceleration%20tab

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt I added a hardcopy of the result of the command `lscpu -e`.